# how to handle inner join and one to many relation with OOP?

Tags: php, inner-join, one-to-many

Let's say I have an author and article tables. One article can have many authors. So it's a one to many relationship. I created an article class and an author class.

```
class author
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($array)
    {
        foreach($array...
    }

    // getters...
    // setters...
}
```

```
class article
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $content;

    private $author = array();

    public function __construct($array)
    {
        foreach($array...
    }

    // getters...
    // setters...

    public function setAuthor(author $author)
    {
        $this->author[] = $author;
    }
}
```

Notice setAuthor, a setter dependency injection. It needs an author object to keep the one to many relationship (one article, many authors).

I retrieve one article with its authors from the database.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT article.id AS id_article, title, content,
GROUP_CONCAT(author.id SEPARATOR ';') AS id_author,
GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ';') AS name FROM article ar
INNER JOIN author au ON ar.id=au.article_id
WHERE article.id=:id GROUP BY article.id"); 

$sql->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

sql->execute();

$fromDb = $sql->fetch();
```

Now I have to build objects, right ?

```
$article['id'] = $fromDb['id_article'];
$article['title'] = $fromDb['title'];
$article['content'] = $fromDb['content'];

$id_author = explode(';', $fromDb['id_author']);
$name = explode(';', $fromDb['name']);

$newArticle = new article($article);

foreach($id_author as $key => $value)
{
   $author['id'] = $value;
   $author['name'] = $name[$key];

   $newArticle->setAuthor(new author($author));
}
```

I find the last part pretty heavy and not practical. I'm not sure it's the right way to do it. Same problem occurs with many to many relationship.

How to use objects once you get the datas from db in this particular case ?

Comment: "Is this how it should be done ?" How what should be done? Given an article, return an array of its articles? What is the exact input & output? "I don't want to use any ORM." What *do* you want to use? Again, clearly state the input including the DB & DBMS API. Give a [mcve]. PS Push as much into one DB query as you can--presumably all of it up to a CSV.

Comment: I just code myself, by hand, in PHP OOP. The SQL request is simple.

Comment: What should be done : handling inner join and one to many relationship with php oop. As the title says. How to use article class and author class with the data I retrieve.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS You still have not answered the questions in my first comment. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: You seem to be asking about something called Active Records. Specifically how to handle loading, or hydrating them. I suggest you research Active Records, and specifically "lazy loading" and "eager loading".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).

An example:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

try {
    $results = $db->query(
          "SELECT *
          FROM articles ar
          INNER JOIN authors au ON ar.id=au.article_id"
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "bad query";
    echo $e;
}

$items = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: your $items is my $fromDb.